# python add specific lists within a list

Tags: python

For this problem I am dealing with a big list,that it was imported from a CSV file, but let's say
I have a list like this:

```
[['name','score1','score2''score3''score4']
 ['Mike','5','1','6','2']
 ['Mike','1','1','1','1']
 ['Mike','3','0','3','0']
 ['jose','0','1','2','3']
 ['jose','2','3','4','5']
 ['lisa','4','4','4','4']]
```

and I want to have another list with this form(the sum of all score for each student):

```
[['Mike','9','2','10','3']
 ['jose','2','4','6','8']
 ['lisa','4','4','4','4']]
```

any ideas how this can be done?
I've been trying many ways, and I could not make it.
I was stuck when there where more than 2 same names, my solution only kept the last 2 lines to add.
I am new in python and programming in general.

Comment: What is the difference between these two formats? Sorry your question is unclear.

Comment: based on first element you are trying to add remaining element in list, for ex: mike is same for 3 list if you add corresponding element in list you will get ['mikke', 5+1+3,1+1+0,6+1+3,2+1+0= = ['mike', 9,2,10,3]

Comment: Learn `python pandas` to solve this problem in one line! You also need to show some code before putting question on stack overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just learning Python I always recommend try to implement things without relying on external libraries.  A good starting step is to start by trying to break the problem up into smaller components:

1. Remove the first entry (the column titles) from the input list.  You don't need it for your result.
2. For each remaining entry:

   1. Convert every entry except the first to an integer (so you can add them).
   2. Determine if you have already encountered an entry with the same name (first column value).  If not: add the entry to the output list.  Otherwise: merge the entry with the one already in the output list (by adding values in the columns).

One possible implementation follows (untested):

```
input_list = [['name','score1','score2''score3''score4'],
              ['Mike','5','1','6','2'],
              ['Mike','1','1','1','1'],
              ['Mike','3','0','3','0'],
              ['jose','0','1','2','3'],
              ['jose','2','3','4','5'],
              ['lisa','4','4','4','4']]
print input_list

# Remove the first element
input_list = input_list[1:]

# Initialize an empty output list
output_list = []

# Iterate through each entry in the input
for val in input_list:
    # Determine if key is already in output list
    for ent in output_list:
        if ent[0] == val[0]:
            # The value is already in the output list (so merge them)
            for i in range(1, len(ent)):
                # We convert to int and back to str
                # This could be done elsewhere (or not at all...)
                ent[i] = str(int(ent[i]) + int(val[i]))
            break
    else:
        # The value wasn't in the output list (so add it)
        # This is a useful feature of the for loop, the following
        # is only executed if the break command wasn't reached above
        output_list.append(val)

#print input_list
print output_list
```

The above is not as efficient as using a dictionary or importing a library that can perform the same operation in a couple of lines, however it demonstrates a few features of the language.  Be careful when working with lists though, the above modifies the input list (try un-commenting the print statement for the input list at the end).

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have

```
In [45]: temp
Out[45]: 
 [['Mike', '5', '1', '6', '2'],
  ['Mike', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
  ['Mike', '3', '0', '3', '0'],
  ['jose', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
  ['jose', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
  ['lisa', '4', '4', '4', '4']]
```

Then, you can use Pandas ...

```
import pandas as pd 

temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
def test(m):
     try:    return int(m)
     except: return m

temp = temp.applymap(test)
print temp.groupby(0).agg(sum)
```

If you are importing it from a cvs file, you can directly read the file using `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

You could use better solution as suggested but if you'd like to implement yourself and learn, you can follow and I will explain in comments:

```
# utilities for iteration. groupby makes groups from a collection
from itertools import groupby
# implementation of common, simple operations such as
# multiplication, getting an item from a list
from operator import itemgetter

def my_sum(groups):
    return [
        ls[0] if i == 0 else str(sum(map(int, ls))) # keep first one since it's name, sum otherwise
        for i, ls in enumerate(zip(*groups)) # transpose elements and give number to each
    ]

# list comprehension to make a list from another list
# group lists according to first element and apply our function on grouped elements
# groupby reveals group key and elements but key isn't needed so it's set to underscore
result = [my_sum(g) for _, g in groupby(ls, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

To understand this code, you need to know about `list comprehension`, `*` operator, (`int`, `enumerate`, `map`, `str`, `zip`) built-ins and some handy modules, `itertools` and `operator`.

You edited to add header which will break our code so we need to remove it  such that we need to pass `ls[1:]` to `groupby` instead of `ls`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is well suited for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

csvdata = [['name','score1','score2','score3','score4'],
           ['Mike','5','1','6','2'],
           ['Mike','1','1','1','1'],
           ['Mike','3','0','3','0'],
           ['jose','0','1','2','3'],
           ['jose','2','3','4','5'],
           ['lisa','4','4','4','4']] 

student_scores = defaultdict(Counter)
score_titles = csvdata[0][1:]
for row in csvdata[1:]:
    student = row[0]
    scores = dict(zip(score_titles, map(int, row[1:])))
    student_scores[student] += Counter(scores)
print(student_scores["Mike"])
# >>> Counter({'score3':10, 'score1':9, 'score4':3, 'score2':2})
```

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner I would consider turning your data into a simpler structure like a dictionary, so that you are just summing a list of list. Assuming you get rid of the header row then you can turn this into a dictionary:

```
>>> data_dict = {}
>>> for row in data:
...     data_dict.setdefault(row[0], []).append([int(i) for i in row[1:]])
>>> data_dict
{'Mike': [[5, 1, 6, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 0, 3, 0]],
 'jose': [[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5]],
 'lisa': [[4, 4, 4, 4]]}
```

Now it should be relatively easy to loop over the dict and sum up the lists (you may want to look a `sum` and `zip` as a way to do that.